# xfce4-clipman actions don't work

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, clipboard-manager

I've defined the following action in `xfce4-clipman`:

```
Name: my_action
Pattern: works

Commands:
Name: my_command
Command: /usr/bin/touch /tmp/my_file
```

I expect that when I highlight the single "works" word in my text the clipman creates `/tmp/my_file` (for testing purposes). The `/tmp/my_file` isn't created.

`xfce4-clipman` itself surely works on my session. It is launched when the session starts. I've the "Sync selections" option set and I can find "works" copied to all selections. The "Enable actions" checkbox is set in `xfce-clipman`.

I use Xubuntu 16.04.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Debian Stretch, clipman 1.4.1) actions only work reliably when "Activate on manual copy" is ticked. Without it the actions menu only appears from time to time.

It seems that this bug isn't completely solved: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12249